# Strange UITableViewCell gap between last two cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a custom UITableViewCell Card style dynamic height and it the spaces are constant through the app. I am using storyboard and I have UIToolbar underneath the UINavigationBar.

[image]

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!_listOfMessages) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (_unreadMessages && [self.segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
        return _unreadMessages.count;
    else
        return _listOfMessages.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WCFeedItem *item;

    if ([self.segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
        item = _unreadMessages[indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        item = _listOfMessages[indexPath.row];
    }

    RKCardInboxCell *cell = (RKCardInboxCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RKCardInboxCell"];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RKCardInboxCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RKCardInboxCell"];
    }
    else {
        [[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99] viewWithTag:97] removeFromSuperview];
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [cell layoutSubviews];

    [cell.profileImage setImageWithURLRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.person.avatar_feed]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"] success:
     ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
         cell.profileImage.image = image;
     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     }];

    [cell setItem:item];


    cell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    CGRect expectedLabelSize = [item.summary boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(268, MAXFLOAT)
                                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.titleLabel.font}
                                                          context:nil];

    //        NSLog(@"size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(expectedLabelSize.size));
    CGRect newFrame = cell.titleLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.size.height;
    cell.titleLabel.frame = newFrame;

    cell.titleLabel.text = item.summary;
    cell.nameLabel.text =  item.person.name;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = item.messageTo;
    [cell.timeButton setTitle:item.date forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if (item.isUnseen) {
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.94 green:0.97 blue:1 alpha:1];

        UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,10,10)];
        circleView.alpha = 0.5;
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.2 blue:0.4 alpha:1.0];
        circleView.tag = 97;
        CGRect timeLabel = [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99] viewWithTag:98].frame;
        circleView.center = CGPointMake((timeLabel.origin.x + timeLabel.size.width) - circleView.frame.size.width, timeLabel.origin.y + timeLabel.size.height + circleView.frame.size.height);
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99] addSubview:circleView];
        //[cell bringSubviewToFront:circleView];
    }


    cell.cardView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 160-8+expectedLabelSize.size.height-5);

    return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];

    NSString *aboutText = [_listOfMessages[indexPath.row] summary];


    // ios 7 only
    CGRect boundingRect = [aboutText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(268, MAXFLOAT)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}
                                                  context:nil];

    CGSize boundingSize = boundingRect.size;
    // end ios7 only

//    [cardSizeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:160-8+boundingSize.height]];

    return (160-8+boundingSize.height);
}
```

Comment: Screenshots and code would make this question better.

Comment: I am going to do that right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because the `cardView` is 300 points wide but `heightForRowAtIndexPath` uses 268 points?  It looks the row in question has text that would probably wrap to two lines at 268 but only one line at 300.  Without seeing the layout code for `RKCardInboxCell` it'll be hard to tell for sure.

As an aside, hardcoding widths like this will make it hard to support wider devices like the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was actually that plus I forgot to set the font size so once I added that it worked like a charm! Also, I will keep that in mind and I wrote it before iPhone 6 and 6 Plus came out!